# Unexpected output when reading .wav data in c++

Tags: c++, file, audio, wav

I'm making a very simple method but experiencing some trouble.

I want to read the data of a .wav file. I am just interested in the first 80 samples, so what I do is the next. 
I use fseek to go to byte 44 of the file (where the data starts) according to
https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/

Then I read in blocks of 24 bits (I'm absolutely sure the .wav file has samples of 24 bits since I created it + checked it)

Here is my code:

```
void WavData::leerTodo(char *fname){
    double array[1000];
    FILE* fp = fopen(fname,"rb");
    fseek(fp, 44, SEEK_SET);
    if (fp) {
        fread(array,sizeof(double), 100, fp);
        for (int i = 0; i<100; i++) {
            cout<<"datos del .wav son es "<<array[i]<<"\n";
        }
    }
}
```

When I compare the results with the data I get from matlab, it's totally different by 10 to the power or 300 or so. I'm using xcode.

Comment: (without reading the format): completely different or different in precision?

Comment: A `double` probably is not 24 bits on your platform...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

24-bit .wav file has *integer* samples, not floating point (float/double) ones; floating point IEEE samples in waves have usually 32 or 64 bits. Just read the data into 32-bit int; note that the alignment, signedness and endianess have to match, too (Wave data is usually signed in two's complement format). Alternatively, as pointed out in the comment, export it to 16-bit to allow easy packing and alignment matching on the data.

For example, Sound Foundry 6.0 allows 8, 16, 24 and 32 bit integer samples and 32 & 64 bit floating IEEE samples; most professional audio applications go along the same lines here, mostly because the hardware supports only those bit resolutions.

further reading:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_bit_depth

Comment: So let me see if I understood. 
I'll explain the whole process:

I generated this .wav file with matlab (expliciting I want 24 bits per sample). 

If I go to byte 34 (it's the part of the header where the number of bits per sample is specified) and read it, I get 24 (as I was expecting).

I tried what you said (reading into 32 bit int, signed or unsigned) and it did not work (I was getting values extremely high). 

If needed, I can post screenshots of the console showing the values I get, even though they are non sense (for me at least).
Thanks

Comment: @mPerezDsp I'm not into MATLAB (I was always pro-Mathematica and con-MATLAB guy), but you should either export the values from MATLAB as 32-bit float or as a 24-bit int; I haven't heard of 24-bit floating point representation used in practice through all my lifetime. Still, for the very sake of easiness of the processing, I'd just stick with 16-bit ints, as they are much easier to pack & align in memory.

Comment: also, simply compare the explicit values using hex viewer/calculator and check what you want and what you do receive; XVI32 has a nice hex calculator, instantly showing what the value would be in different bases (byte, word, integer, long int, IEEE single, IEEE double)

Comment: "Solved" it producing .wav of 16 bits per sample and reading into short type of data. 
Could not make it work in 24bit mode. Thank you all.

Comment: @mPerezDsp if the information has been useful to you and allowed you to solve the problem, accepting the answer would be more than welcome, as it's used to both signify that the problem has been solved *and* to reward the people helping.